# Wine menu directory location?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, wine, menu

Using the menu editor I accidentally deleted the WINE menu. Now I am stuck with the application installed and no way to easily use parts of it. I tried reinstalling it, many times, and still the menu does not show up. I think that a directory exists where the menu is at, but it is just marked off as deleted. Can anyone point me to this directory or tell me another way to get the WINE menu back?

Comment: better look at this http://askubuntu.com/a/19477/47206

Answer (score 5):

You will need to recreate those entries in `alacarte` (System -> Preferences -> Main Menu) and recreate your entries.

Typically the Wine menu will still be there - only hidden. Once you have alacarte open check to make sure you don't have a Wine entry already there:

[image: WINE]

If you do not click on `Applications` on the left column then select New Menu from the right. Enter the following details

[image]

Once you've named the menu click the Icon on the right of the New Menu Dialog to choose the Icon. I've included the path for the Wine image in the following screenshot:

[image]

After closing the new Menu dialog select Wine from the list on the left column. You'll need to recreate the following items:

[image]

You can recreate the Applications directory by following the steps above for adding the Wine Menu item. For *Browse C: Drive* You will need to add a "New Item" with the following fields entered:

[image]

Repeat this for both *Configure Wine* and *Uninstall Wine Software*

[image]

[image]

Finally to add back applications from Wine to the Applications folder navigate to the Applications folder on the left column and select "New Item" using the following example as a template:

[image]

Replacing the `WINEPREFIX` path with the path to your Wine Prefix (Typically `/home/<USER>/.wine`) and the path to the Applications executable.