# No Wine menu showing up in main menu

Tags: wine, menu

I have uninstalled Wine and then reinstalled a few weeks later, now there is no Wine menu in the main menu. I can't get to anything Wine related.

How do I reset the menu so Wine shows up?

Comment: Type `winecfg` in terminal..And let me see if it helps you..

Comment: Yes wine config opens, but I still have no wine menu.

Comment: Look at [this](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-34c8b5d78823a60c9651b4c9848c06a1aa8fea48)

Comment: That link did the trick, all wine menus are back. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than actually delete anything, menu editors on Linux simply mark menus as "Deleted" so that they don't show up in the menu. First, see if the directory is in your menu editor and can be re-enabled.

This information is stored in ~/.config/menus/applications.menu . Edit ~/.config/menus/applications.menu and you should find a section near the end that looks similar to this:

```
    <Menu>
            <Name>wine-wine</Name>
            <Deleted/>
    </Menu>
```

or perhaps this:

```
    <Menu>
            <Name>wine-wine</Name>
            <Menu>
                    <Name>wine-Programs</Name>
                    <Menu>
                            <Name>wine-Programs-AutoHotkey</Name>
                            <DirectoryDir>/home/user/.local/share/desktop-directories</DirectoryDir>
                    </Menu>
            </Menu>
            <Deleted/>
    </Menu>
```

Remove the `<Deleted/>` line and your Wine menu will reappear.

**[Source](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-34c8b5d78823a60c9651b4c9848c06a1aa8fea48)**

Comment: I don't have a applications.menu folder in the /.config/menus folder, also I use Kubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

First go to System → Preferences → Main Menu and make you sure there is item Wine and is't checked.

[image]

If there's no Wine entry, open Nautilus (ubuntu default file browser), press Crl+H to show hidden files/folders, goto `.config/menus` and delete here file `application.menu` -- Gnome will automatically recreate this file with default application menu configuration.

Comment: wine is not showing up there. Will I lose my custom shortcuts if I delete the application-menu?

Comment: Yes, you will. It's probably not the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps, but for me I just went into synaptic package manager and installed Q4wine to add the GUI with wine and made sure wine was also installed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running with command line instead:

```
wine <PATH_TO_FILE>
```