# Recover Wine menus in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: wine, lubuntu, menu

Some error deleted my Wine menus. (LX Panel was crashed by another app and the Wine menu was gone)

Wine is installed but not visible in the menu.

Do not flag as clone of similar questions (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/6249/47206) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/19470/47206)) because: these likely refer to Ubuntu main and not to Lubuntu, which means that:

- **Alcarte** is not an option in Lubuntu (it does not work or does randomly - [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/196614/47206) and [the end of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/205908/47206)). I have tried it again anyway and Wine was absent there too, and cannot change it.
- Considering [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/19477/47206) answer, I have not found any 'wine' term in that file, nor in others that I found with similar name, excepting:

  `/etc/xdg/menus/lxlauncher-applications.menu`

which contains the lines

```
<Move>
        <Old>wine-wine</Old>
        <New>Work/wine-wine</New>
```

and `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/applications.menu`

which contains

```
<Menu>

  <Name>Applications</Name>
  <Directory>X-GNOME-Menu-Applications.directory</Directory>

  <AppDir>.</AppDir>

  <!-- we disable those here, otherwise we see e.g. wine menus -->
  <!-- Read standard .directory and .desktop file locations -->
  <!-- <DefaultAppDirs/> -->
  <!-- Read in overrides and child menus from applications-merged/ -->
  <!-- <DefaultMergeDirs/> -->
```

and also in `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged`, with the content

```
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd">
<Menu>
  <Name>Applications</Name>
  <Menu>
    <Name>wine-wine</Name>
    <Directory>wine-wine.directory</Directory>
    <Include>
      <Category>Wine</Category>
    </Include>
  <Menu>
    <Name>wine-Programs</Name>
    <Directory>wine-Programs.directory</Directory>
    <Include>
        <Category>Wine-Programs</Category>
    </Include>
  <Menu>
    <Name>wine-Programs-Accessories</Name>
    <Directory>wine-Programs-Accessories.directory</Directory>
    <Include>
        <Category>Wine-Programs-Accessories</Category>
    </Include>
  </Menu>
  </Menu>
  </Menu>
</Menu>
```

But cannot see what could be changed here according to that answer.

**LXMenuEditor** does not display Wine at all and it cannot create main categories anyway  as Alacarte would ([see this](https://askubuntu.com/a/199206/47206)), and Wine was a such category.

**`menulibre` ("Menu Editor") displays Wine and its submenus.**

[image: wine]

[image]

But the Wine menu visibility cannot be edited in this app. The same problem of not being able to create main categories (as Alacarte would), but only items. That is, individual items can be created and set to appear in certain categories but there's no setting on these very categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial workaround:

Wine **subcategories** (Browse C Drive, Uninstall Wine Programs etc) may be set in `menulibre` to appear within visible main menu categories: putting them all in 'System' and adding "Wine" at the beginning of their name makes them all appear grouped together under `System Tools`

[image]

[image]

This looks easier to do in `menulibre`, which now also supports Quantal 12.10.
To get the same results in **LXMenuEditor**, edit and add these entries under one of the main menu categories:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the file

```
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/applications.menu
```

uncomment the lines

```
<!-- Read standard .directory and .desktop file locations -->
<DefaultAppDirs/>
<!-- Read in overrides and child menus from applications-merged/ -->
<DefaultMergeDirs/>
```

probably just uncommenting

```
<DefaultMergeDirs/>
```

does the trick.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

12.04 is a LTS version, so I have a lot of machines at my job running it...

Yo have to make a symbolic link to **applications-merged** folder for each desktop used. For example, for **lxde** and **unity** will be:

```
cd /etc/xdg/menus
sudo ln -s applications-merged lxde-applications-merged
sudo ln -s applications-merged unity-lens-applications-merged
```

You need also to ensure that the **Categories=** line for your wine programs launchers are ok. wine configuration is for each user. So, yo have to go to:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs
```

and ensure that each **.desktop** file have at mininum

```
Categories=Wine-Programs
```

If you want to see the application at other Categories, add them. Example:

```
Categories=Wine-Programs;Graphics;Education
```

Folder **~/.config/menus** has similar structure than **/etc/xdg/menu** So, symbolic link to its **applications-merged** subfolder displays submenues at ***Wine - Programs*** for installed wine applications:

```
cd ~/.config/menus
ln -s applications-merged lxde-applications-merged
```

Some years ago I used **alacarte**. But now I prefer to modify menues and launchers using a text editor. I'm more sure that I'm doing. Specially if the computer uses different desktops (such lxde and unity).