# Nvidia driver installed, then can't login (Ubuntu 14.04; Today is May 2017)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I believe this is a very common problem with Nvidia GPU and I see a lot of discussion about it. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6249) from two yrs ago. I followed the suggested solutions but nothing works. So I suspect it's still unresolved. Can someone please give an update on what works for ubuntu 14.04.

Here is how i got into this mess. So please don't repeat.

I have a new Dell Precision 5810 with an entry level Nvidia card (NVS 310) and the Nvidia driver pre-installed. I want to replace it with a GeForce GTX 660 Ti. So I went to the Nvidia site and download `cuda_7.5.18_linux.run` and ran it at Ctrl-Alt-F1.

The install succeeded, ie. I did not see any error msg.

After reboot, the login screen at terrible resolution came back. When I type password, it flashes then give the same login screen again. So basically, login fails.

I went to command line again (Ctrl-Alt-F1) and type

```
lshw -c video
```

and I see

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
  description: VGA compatible controller
  product: GF119 [NVS 310]
  vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
  physical id: 0
  .....
  configuration: latency=0
  resources: memory ......
*-display ...
  ......
  product: GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti]
  ....
```

I tried the following :

a. try to uninstall all Nvidia stuff by,

```
cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --uninstall
```

b. following Nvidia doc, I type

```
nvidia-uninstall
```

I still couldn't get ride of Nvidia driver. Here is my system info

kernel : 3.19.0-80-generic

Comment: Did you adjust your xorg.conf or did you switch the graphic card and left your settings untouched?

Comment: @Ziazis I did not touch xorg.conf. If that's what's needed, pls tell me how to adjust it.

Comment: @Ziazis I checked, xorg.conf does not exist.